# EF Core: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process happening spontaneously

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have issues with our SQL Server express install on the staging environment. The following exception happens in spontaneous intervals and it requires the .NET Core app to be restarted to fix the issue.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)
```

Locally the issue never happens, I have tried the following things to fix the issue but to no avail.

- Use SQL Server Developer Version
- Migrate the SQL Server instance to its own Droplet
- Run the SQL Server instance in Docker next to the app using the instance.

Did anyone face the issue before and find a fix for it?

Comment: Try executing `exec sp_readerrorlog` to see if you can find the underlying issue, and edit your question accordingly. Security exceptions don't contain any information by design.

Comment: If restarting the app fixes the issue then it sounds like you're running out of connections in your Connection Pool(s). SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects are IDisposable - are you always using them in `using (...) {...}` blocks?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I thought too that it could be a connection pool issue, I'm using only EFCore however and im not doing any manual queries outside of that, so no SqlConnection/SqlCommands anywhere in the code.